# Редактирование файла | JS

Tags: javascript, парсер, файлы, редактор, blob

Экспериментирую с шифрованием на js и решил попробовать зашифровать файл. Покопался в интернете и не нашел однозначного ответа, как взять содержимое файла, отредактировать, и дать возможность "это" скачать.

Думаю в сторону Blob. Нашел как конвертировать все в различные числовые форматы, а как назад - не знаю.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону гуглить)

Хочу попробовать два варианта:

1. Зашифровать только информацию, сохранив мета-данные и название.
2. Зашифровать полностью все данные, создать свой файл со своим расширением, а при расшифровке достать только информацию и создать из нее изначальный файл.

В двух вариантах нужен доступ непосредственно к данным файла, без меток, типа и названий (как на скрине)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что непонятно то? Что не получается?

Comment: @DiD достать информацию из файла (не важно в каком виде), редактировать (это ок). А не получается: положить обратно, и скачать файл

Comment: И причем там Blob? и как вы его "конвертируете" в числовой формат?  Blob практически невозможно записать в Number, а если и можно, то восстановить Number до Blob будет в разы сложнее...

Comment: @DiD .arrayBuffer()
Этот способ выглядит самым походящим) Я не знаю как правильно работать с файлами

Comment: А какой алгоритм шифрования используете? Симметричное или ассиметричное шифрование? Какие библиотеки используете? Как формируется ключ?

Comment: Зачем вам ArrayBuffer если вы работаете с текстовой информацией?

Comment: @DiD чисто свое шифрование, без библиотек. Но разницы нету, условно будет две функции:  `encrypt(string)` и `decrypt(encryptedString)`.

Comment: @DiD файл может быть любым. Видео, фото, аудио. Поэтому должен быть универсальный формат

Comment: Вы собираетесь изобрести собственный алгоритм шифрования?

Comment: @DiD уже изобрел) Не собиираюсь серьезно это продвигать, просто Эксперимент. Вопрос не о нем)

Comment: Я так и не понял что вы хотите, шифровать, редактировать тексты или видео, но что касается шифрования, вы можете воспользоваться простенькой библиотекой [sjcl](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/): есть отличное [демо](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/) и детальная [документация](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/). Будете работать с sjcl - проблем знать не будете и глупые вопросы отпадут сами собой...

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из комментариев, если вас устроит number, то можно поэкспериментировать с такими трансформациями

```
const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer(); // ArrayBuffer
const numbers = Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer)); // number[]
const file = new File([new Uint8Array(numbers).buffer], 'fileName'); // File
```